# Escaping html Tags in xls

Tags: html, excel, tags, escaping, xls

We've got a report that wraps the title of the report in <>'s then exports the resulting file as an xls. If that title contains an HTML tag name (e.g. "head", "body", "html") excel interprets the file as html and tries to render it as a web page. Is there a way to escape a valid html tag in xls while maintaining the angle brackets?

Here's what an errant report looks like raw:

```
<Head Ache>
Category
Some Data
Some More Data 


=CONCATENATE(CHAR(169), "Copyright info")
```